# My routes are defined but express gives back a 404 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have checked every duplicate here on `StackOverflow` but none of which solved the problem...

Here is my `app.js` the first file that `express` library looks for when running the app after my `server.js` file that's used to create a server.

You can have a look at the comments in the code to better understand the problem

```js
// Implement cors
app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/', viewRouter); // This route works
app.use('/signup', userRouter); // This route doesn't work
app.use('/test', userRouter); // This route doesn't work
module.exports = app;
```

And this is my `userRouter.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const authController = require('../controllers/authController');

// See below for the code snippet for these two functions

router.route('/signup').get(authController.test); // When I visit this route it gives back a 404;

router.post('/signup', authController.signup); // When I visit this route it gives back a 404;


router.get('/test', (req, res) => { // When I visit this route it gives back a 404;
  res.send('Hello, World!');
});

console.log('Express can run me'); // I can get this log on my terminal which means the file is run but I can't get the routes to above to work!

module.exports = router;
```

This is the `authController.js` that has the code for my two functions

```js
const User = require('../models/userModel');

exports.signup = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // Get the data from req.body and add it to the database;
    const user = await User.create(req.body);

    res.status(201).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: {
        user,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: 'fail',
      message: err,
    });
  }
};

exports.test = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Inside the test function'); // Doesn't get logged to the terminal!

  const test = 'This is the test data';
  res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      test,
    },
  });
};
```

Can anyone help with this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you were visiting those routes, they wouldn't give you a 404. Which means you are probably visiting the wrong routes. But you didn't give us enough information (e.g. what URLs you are visiting) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not an express expert, but you've set up the user router to use `/signup` in your app, so I think you don't need to repeat the "signup" route in your post and other methods within your userRouter file: `router.post('/', authController.signup);` etc..., but 100% sure about that

Comment: @Quentin
I'm visiting the routes like that ``localhost:5000/signup`` and ``localhost:5000/test`` and returns ``Cannot GET /test``

Comment: @NickParsons I know but I need to separate the files that is why I did that

Comment: @HusseinAl-Mosawi I'm not saying to remove the separate files, I'm saying that I think your router already catches routes pointed to `/signup`.  So maybe doing `localhost:5000/signup/signup` would work

Comment: @NickParsons, Yes you're right! I didn't know that... Thanks a lot it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm visiting the routes like that localhost:5000/signup

But your Router has `router.route('/signup')` and the router is mounted at `app.use('/signup', userRouter);` which makes the path `/signup/signup` not `/signup`.

There is no `/` in the router mounted to `/signup` so the URL isn't found.